# E: Package 'python-certbot-nginx' has no installation candidate

Tags: bash, nginx, apt, certbot

When I try to install Certbot for Nginx and run

```
sudo apt-get install python-certbot-nginx
```

I get

```
E: Package 'python-certbot-nginx' has no installation candidate
```

How to install Certbot for Nginx?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Since Python2 is no longer supported you just need to ask for Python3.

So

```
sudo apt-get install python3-certbot-nginx
```

should solve your Problem.

Answer (score 0):

This error message frequently appears when a package management, such as apt, tries to install the "python-certbot-nginx" package, but the package cannot be found in the repository or the repository has been setup incorrectly.

You can install it on your system by running the following command in your terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-certbot-nginx
```